# Hide scrollbars of a iframe with javascript (Firefox, Opera and IE)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, iframe, opera

I have [a website that needs to work without javascript](http://planner.gvb.reizenapp.nl/advice?utf8=%E2%9C%93&plan%5Binput_from%5D=Lindenlaan,%20Amstelveen&plan%5Binput_from_pred_id%5D=4d3a67b9868060eaab4a92cf5d9932bf5b12f3d6&plan%5Binput_from_loc%5D=52.2939036,4.855229699999995&plan%5Binput_to%5D=Lindengracht,%20Amsterdam&plan%5Binput_to_pred_id%5D=3d9fc242ce093e749c5bb23227d6a61a53aec8e3&plan%5Binput_to_loc%5D=52.3800625,4.884104200000024&plan%5Bendpoint_date_time%5D=12-12-2012%2020:18&plan%5Bendpoint_type%5D=Vertrek&plan%5Btransports%5D%5B%5D=bus&plan%5Btransports%5D%5B%5D=train&plan%5Btransports%5D%5B%5D=metro&plan%5Btransports%5D%5B%5D=ferry&plan%5Btransports%5D%5B%5D=tram).

In this website I show a iframe which contains the main content of the page. Because of a no javascript requirement, I have to show the iframe initially with scrolling. I want the scrollbars when there is no javascript.

If javascript is available, I resize the Iframe. I have to because the content of the page changes. Is it possible to remove the scrollbars when the frame is resized? Chrome and Safari hide the iframe scrollbars when its contents fit, so no issues there.

Is this possible in:

- Firefox 13
- IE 9
- Opera 12

I've tried to do the following in javascript:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('planneriframe'); 
iframe.setAttribute('style', 'style="overflow: hidden;"');
iframe.setAttribute('verticalscrolling', 'no"');
iframe.setAttribute('scrolling', 'no"');
```

it does add/change all the attributes, but the scrollbar is not hidden.

Solutions taking another approach or working javascript are welcome.

UPDATE

A better link to the site: http://planner.gvb.reizenapp.nl/advice
This contains no javascript for resizing the iframe tough, buts that not really relevant I think.

Comment: Can't you just set `overflow: auto` for  the `body` within the `iframe`? BTW, it seems the link in the post is broken.

Comment: I'll try handling the scrollbars in the framed site. Changed the link in the post.

Comment: Those scrollbars are inside the iframe, not in the `iframe` element itself. Maybe `iframeID.contentWindow.document.body.style = 'overflow: hidden`? Links are still broken (Can't find the server) : (.

Comment: Why wont the link work? :( Anyway, solving the problem inside the framed site worked perfectly.